2 generated groups, with generators of order 3
I can show that if $G$ is a group generated by  $a$ and $b$, with $a^2=b^2=1$, then $G$ is a finite elementary abelian 2 group or a dihedral group (finite or infinite), depending whether $ab$ has finite or infinite order.
What about if $a^3=b^3=1$? (and in general is there a way to find structure of 2 generated groups in which generators have the same finite order?)

They will be quotients of $\Bbb Z_3*\Bbb Z_3$.

But does this say much about the structure of such groups?

As the answer of @Shaun suggests, you are more-or-less asking about the structure of all normal subgroups of $\mathbb Z_3 * \mathbb Z_3$, of which there are a lot.

@LeeMosher Yes there are alot and I am asking if anything is known.

At this point I would say that your question has become somewhat vague. The answer of @Shaun is probably the best you are going to get. I don't think there is any structure theorem for normal subgroups of $\mathbb Z_3 * \mathbb Z_3$.

Perhaps you can think of it this way. $\mathbb Z_3 * \mathbb Z_3$ is not so far removed from finite rank free groups. For example, it contains an index $3$ subgroup that is free of rank $2$, and therefore it contains finite index free subgroups of all ranks. Classifying all quotients of $\mathbb Z_3 * \mathbb Z_3$ would then be very closely to potentially classifying all quotients of finite rank free groups... which is to say, all finitely generated groups.

@LeeMosher Aha I see, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2$ has no free subgroups which is why the question is much easier there. Thanks.

$Z_3* Z_3$ is SQ-universal: It admits a quotient group $G$  such that every recursively-presentable group embeds in $G$. There is no hope of classifying such groups in any meaningful sense.

Why was this closed as lacking context? Literally, it starts with what they can show . . .

The group $G=\langle a,b\mid a^d=b^d=1\rangle$ has a free subgroup of rank $(d-1)^2$: it is the commutator subgroup, and $G$ is a finite extension of this free group. This makes it somewhat clear why the $d=2$ case is special, because that's the only time this free subgroup is Abelian.

One way to look at this is in terms of presentations. Essentially, you're asking about presentations $P:=\langle a,b\mid a^3, b^3, R\rangle$, where $R$ is a set of words in $a,b$. But $P$ is simply a presentation of a quotient of the free product $\Bbb Z_3\ast\Bbb Z_3$; namely,
$$P\cong\langle a,b\mid a^3, b^3\rangle/\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle,$$
where $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ is the normal subgroup of $\Bbb Z_3\ast\Bbb Z_3$ generated by $R$.
I am not aware of any classification of such quotients.
See here:
Subgroups of free products of cyclic groups

as I have written in the comments, this   a rephrasing of my question.
